# How to extract a JSON object from the resulting JSON array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following code to get the results of a query. The query results are in the form of JSON.

```
$.ajax({
    url: ..... //url//...,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "type": "daysofyear",
        "entity": {
            "year": "2015"
        }
    }),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        if ((result) && (result.isSuccess == true)) {
            alert("SUCCESS");
            alert(json.entity.day);
        }
    },
});
```

The returned JSON is:

```
{
    "isSuccess": true,
    "results": [{
        "jsonClass": "RuleSuccess",
        "message": "Found mapping for year: 2015",
        "rule": {
            "name": "Year rule",
            "metadata": {}
        },
        "entity": {
            "year": "2015",
            "month": "December",
            "day": "Saturday"
        }
    }]
}
```

Im basically trying to extract the value of month, year, day separately and display them alone using

```
alert(json.entity.day);
```

Please advice.

Comment: just use result.rule.entity.day?

Comment: The structure of the data is literally in front of you. You really just have to look at it. What is the issue? Are you not aware that `[...]` represents an array? Where is `json` defined anyway?

Comment: @FelixKling actually I wasnt. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

```js
var a =JSON.parse('{"isSuccess":true,"results":[{"jsonClass":"RuleSuccess","message":"Found mapping for year: 2015","rule": {"name":"Year rule","metadata":{}}, "entity":{"year":"2015", "month":"December",  "day":"Saturday"}}]}') ;


alert(a.results[0].entity.day);
```

**Original**

Use

```
alert(result[0].rule.entity.day);
```

Comment: `result[0]` - response is in an array

Comment: @tymeJV: yes was a miss..edited now thanks :)

Comment: Im getting an error saying result[0] is undefined.

Comment: @pal: Then `result` is not what you claim it to be. Which is not surprising since you are accessing `result.isSuccess`, but `isSuccess` is not even listed as property in the response example you provided. At this point is completely unclear what the value of `result` is. `json` is not defined either.

Comment: Correct @pal please confirm once again :)

Comment: I updated the Json response.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got the answer. It is 
`alert(result.results[0].entity.day);`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj[0].rule.entity.day);
```

Comment: The response is auto-parsed by jQuery since the `dataType` was set to JSON - Also, `obj` is an array, so `obj[0]`